# jQuery <audio> Plugin Doesn't work in Firefox and Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, soundcloud

I was working with a plugin for custom `<audio>` player and everything was fine. I was working in Safari browser on Mac OSX 10.8.2 , Once I decided to test project in other browsers things got very strange. In a nutshell, plugin is supposed to find `<audio>` tags in a page and than change them to a different custom markup. Works fine in safari, but doesn't seem to work in firefox and opera

Firefox and Opera have following issue, there is a part in a plugin which, in case if audio source is unsupported format, creates different (mini) player which is basically a fallback for older browsers, however I don't see how firefox and opera show this fallback player, as both are very modern browsers.

Plugin originally comes from: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/ however I have made several changes e.g.

```
canPlayType   = function( type )
        {
        var audioElement = document.createElement( 'audio' );
        return !!( audioElement.canPlayType && 
                   audioElement.canPlayType( 'audio/' + type.toLowerCase() + ';' ).replace( /no/, '' ) );
        };
```

**and original is**

```
canPlayType   = function( file )
        {
            var audioElement = document.createElement( 'audio' );
            return !!( audioElement.canPlayType &&
                    audioElement.canPlayType( 'audio/' + file.split( '.' ).pop().toLowerCase() + ';' ).replace( /no/, '' ) );
        };
```

**and another small change**

```
else if( canPlayType( 'mp3' ) ) isSupport = true;
```

**where as original is**

```
else if( canPlayType( audioFile ) ) isSupport = true;
```

These modifications were made to specify that file in src is an mp3, instead of automatically detecting it (as I am not using local files, but instead soundcloud api generated url's). I can't see how such changes could have affected browsers to not work with a plugin. As there are many code files involved, Instead of posting them all here, I created a **dropbox folder for you to see them all yourself here, you can try index.html file in different browsers so you can see what issues I am talking about:** https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xutioz3hyrybvz3/f0-528WzH0

---

**EDIT:** I also created a live demo on jsbin http://jsbin.com/unupov/1/edit so you can see how player behaves in different browsers

**EDIT 2:** Ignore issues with chrome, thanks to *user20140268* those have been fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed links to CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/player.css">
```

As well as to scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/player.js"></script>
```

Now it works well in [chrome](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3mvue5otbm4vbgd/Capture.PNG)

**Update:**
It seems that both firefox and opera [don't support mp3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats) in `<audio/>`.
In this case player.js fallbacks `<audio/>` tag to `<embed/>`.
There is no API to control playback for `<embed/>` instead you can use flash or make `<embed/>` visible changing player.js at `line 70`

```
var thePlayer = !isSupport 
            ? $('<embed src="' + audioFile + '" width="100%" height="25" volume="100" autostart="' + isAutoPlay.toString() +'" loop="' + isLoop.toString() + '" />')
            : $( '<div class="' + params.classPrefix + '">' + $( '<div>' ).append( $this.eq( 0 ).clone() ).html() + '<div class="' + cssClass.playPause + '" title="' + params.strPlay + '"><a href="#">' + params.strPlay + '</a></div></div>' ),
```

and deleting `thePlayer.addClass( cssClass.mini );` at `line 171`

Comment: indeed fixed issue with chrome, however firefox and opera are still behaving strangely ;/ I'll edit my question to get rid of chrome issue

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, Didn't expect that firefox would not support mp3 files, I will give you a bounty once stack overflow lets me do so ;))

Answer (score 0):

The file type `mp3` may have different meta type, that you may define properly to make it work

```
audio/x-mpeg-3
```

or

```
audio/mpeg3
```

or

```
audio/mpeg
```

try one of these in

```
audioElement.canPlayType('audio/' + type.toLowerCase() + ';' )
```

I think this might work, as Firefox and opera behave with strict JS and datatypes also they don't support some formats!

try and reply if it worked or not :)

Comment: Hi, yea I tried them out x-mpeg-3 doesn't work at all, mpeg3 only works in safari (for some reason google chrome didn't like it) and as far as I know now, firefox and opera don't support mp3 format ;/