# jQuery partially not working in firefox and opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, opera, mozilla

I'm testing my webpage in browsers and it seems that some bits are not working in firefox and opera. I assume it's caused by jQuery used on my page.

This is my website: http://freshbeer.lv/ht/index.html

At the bottom of the source code you can find all jQuery code used (mainly to call and apply plugins). I'm having trouble to determine what is wrong, as there are no errors shown in console (firefox 20.0) Main dysfunctions are

1. player, just compare how it works in chrome and than check it out in firefox or opera, first of all it doesn't show "..." which signifies loading, secondly once you click play on another player, both songs keep playing, where as in other browsers first song would pause, so there would be only one song playing.
2. advertisement should have margins on top and bottom calculated by jQuery, it doesn't in opera and firefox.
   So Am I missing something? Maybe I need to apply certain code standards?

That seems to be all, however I can't be sure.

I'll put code written by me here (most likely issue is in it), note, there are several jQuery plugins included above it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//Audio Player
audiojs.events.ready(function () {
    var as = audiojs.createAll();

        $('audio').each(function () {
            var myAudio = this;
            this.addEventListener('play', function () {
                $('audio').each(function () {
                    if (!(this === myAudio)) {
                        this.pause();
                    }
            });
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Responsive add margins
    function addMargin () {
        var add = $(".advert");
        var addMargin = add.css("margin-left");
        add.css({
            "margin-top": addMargin,
            "margin-bottom": addMargin
        });
    }
    addMargin();
    $(window).resize(addMargin);

    //Responsive Grid
    var MusicGrid = (function() {
        var $musicGridContainer = $('.grid'),
            init = function() {
                changeMusicGrid();
                initEvents();
                initPlugins();
            },
        changeMusicGrid = function() {
            var w_w = $(window).width();
            if (w_w <= 765) n = 1;
            else if (w_w <= 1180) n = 2;
            else n = 3;
        },
        initEvents = function() {
            $(window).on('smartresize.MusicGrid', function(event) {
                changeMusicGrid();
            });
        },
        initPlugins = function() {
            $musicGridContainer.imagesLoaded(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $musicGridContainer.masonry({
                        itemSelector: '.article',
                        columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
                            return containerWidth / n;
                        },
                        isAnimated: true,
                        animationOptions: {
                            duration: 150
                        }
                    });
                }, 500);
            });
        };
        return {
            init: init
        };
    })();
    MusicGrid.init();
});


//Preload Content
function preloadCode() {
    if (preloadCode.done) return;
    preloadCode.done = true;
    clearTimeout(t);

    $(".preloader").css("display", "none");
    $(".grid").css({ opacity: 0, visibility: 'visible', marginTop: 20 }).animate({ marginTop: 0, opacity: 1 }, 550);

    $('.article[id^="article-"]').each(function () {
        if (parseInt(this.id.replace('article-', '')) % 3 === 0) {
            $('#' + this.id).css({ marginTop: 50 }).animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 350);
        } else if (parseInt(this.id.replace('article-', '')) % 2 === 0) {
            $('#' + this.id).css({ marginTop: 100 }).animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 400);
        } else {
            $('#' + this.id).css({ marginTop: 150 }).animate({ marginTop: 0 }, 450);
        }
    });

    $(".footer").css("display", "block");

}

var t = setTimeout(preloadCode, 6000);
$(window).load(preloadCode);

</script>
```

Comment: It would be better to put relevant code here.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Ok, I'll include code that I wrote, as I don't think it should be something to do with plugins I included ;/

Comment: In FF, `var addMargin = add.css("margin-left");` is returning `0px`. Where is the left margin being set in the first place?

Comment: @Barmar in css margin is set to margin: 0 auto; therefore it takes value of left margin and applies to top and bot, so to make them responsive.

Comment: I think you're seeing a difference in how `.css("margin-left")` works when it's set to `auto`. Some browsers return the computed margin, others return the declared margin, which isn't set.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is, though, because other questions regarding `auto` indicate that jQuery should always return the computed style.

Comment: @Barmar I know it's strange, furthermore margins are not the only issue ;/

Comment: @Evan Just tried it, no luck. In fact it resulted in content not loading up at all.

Comment: @llya I mis-typed - `(function($) {  //plugin code })(jQuery);`

Comment: @Evan This time content loads, but still none of the issues are solved ;/

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276578/jquery-audio-plugin-doesnt-work-in-firefox-and-opera Apparently Firefox and Opera don't support mp3 files in <audio>. And soundcloud returns an mp3.

Comment: @RomainBraun This is handled by audio.min.js plugin, it provides flash fallback for firefox and opera.

Comment: @Ilya Then, if your audio is replaced by a flash object, it's normal that it doesn't fire a 'play' event, isn't it ?

Comment: @Ilya Also, it would seem that this plugin returns pixel values of margins when they're set to auto : http://www.bramstein.com/projects/jsizes/

Comment: @RomainBraun Oh flip, forgot that I'm not pausing flash, can you suggest what to use instead of `$('audio').each(function () {
            var myAudio = this;
            this.addEventListener('play', function () {
                $('audio').each(function () {
                    if (!(this === myAudio)) {
                        this.pause();
                        $(this).closest('div').removeClass("playing");
                    }
             });
         });
  });` to apply same functionality when flash is used?

Comment: @Ilya Reading their docs, it looks like you have to use ppause(); http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/

Comment: @RomainBraun changed `this.pause();` to `this.ppause();` doesn't work, I'm  not quiet sure I understand what you mean. reading through documentation doesn't explain much to me.

Comment: @Ilya if you do audiojs.instances.audiojs0.play() you can play your song.

Comment: @RomainBraun so audiojs.instances.ppause(); should pause them all (In my case I can't specify concrete element e.g. audiojs0, as they are dynamic)

Comment: @Ilya Alright let me think about it. Have you tried the jssizes plugin already ?

Comment: @RomainBraun playing with it while we are talking (like how lightweight it is), so far so good, I don't think I'll have problems with it and it seems to solve the margin issue. So, fixing that player functionality in firefox is something I need help atm.

Comment: @Ilya I swear I'll find what the problem is. I want my bounty ! :D

Comment: @RomainBraun Sure thing, I just wan't to get done with this issue so I can finalise my project ;)

Comment: Alright here's what I found. When you setup your players with createAll() you should store this in a global value. Then, you can access 'as', which is going to be an array of players. Then you simply have to call as[0].play() or .pause() to control it.

Comment: @RomainBraun Alright, so doing a for loop to pause them all e.g. as[i].pause(); should work, problem is that I need to play one of them, one which user clicked play on. and I think it will only pause in browsers that support mp3? do you have skype so we can chat, as I don't have enough reputation atm to chat here.

Comment: @Ilya yes. thor881991

Comment: @RomainBraun added you, just in case this is my one: Ilja-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. advertisement should have margins on top and bottom calculated by jQuery, it doesn't in opera and firefox. So Am I missing something? Maybe I need to apply certain code standards?**

Your element has auto margins, so, depending on the browser, `.css('margin-left')` might return different values, including `0`.

I recommend using the [JsSizes library](http://bramstein.com/projects/jsizes) which is a lightweight plugin that will allow you to get the actual margins in pixels.

**2. player, just compare how it works in chrome and than check it out in firefox or opera, first of all it doesn't show "..." which signifies loading, secondly once you click play on another player, both songs keep playing, where as in other browsers first song would pause, so there would be only one song playing.**

Firefox and Opera don't support mp3 in their audio element, so it gets replaced by a flash object. Therefore you can't listen to those DOM events anymore.

Although, according to their [annotated source code](http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/), the flash object has public methods `play()`, `pause()`, and `isPlaying`.

I'd recommend listening a click event on the 'play-pause' button and use these functions. Like this :

```
var as = ''; // You're going to have to make your as variable global to access it outside of your function.
audiojs.events.ready(function () {
    as = audiojs.createAll();
    $('.audiojs .play-pause').click(function(){ //Listening to the click event
        var thisIndex = $(this).parents('.audiojs').index('.audiojs'); // When you create several players, as is an array of instances of players. Here we're finding the DOM index of the player so it reflects its position in the as array.
        $.each(as, function(index,val){ //then, for each instance of players in the as array
            if ( index != thisIndex && as[index].playing ) as[index].pause(); //If the player is already playing, and its index is different than the one we just clicked on, pause it !
        });
    });
});
```